# Problems with gzencode

Tags: php, http-headers, gzip

All right with you?

I built an application to abstract the output of html in a compressed and uncompressed way.

The hosting sites I use in the company where I work do not always support "native" compression.

Good site hosting takes the output of the script and compresses it and adds the necessary headers so that the browser does the work of decompressing when they receive the response from the server.

See the following code:

```php
header_remove();
header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset="WingedConfig::$config->HTML_CHARSET);
header ('Cache-Control: private, no-cache, max-age = 3600');
if ($use_gzencode) {
    header ("Content-Encoding: gzip");
    echo gzencode($content, 9);
} else {
    echo $content;
}
```

`$use_gzencode` : is true if the client request allows compression and if the compression option is enabled in the application configuration file

`$content` : is my entire html, including `<!doctype html>` and everything else

On my local server everything works fine, however in the production environment I have the following page.

[image: content malformed by gzencode function can not be decoded?]

Follows the headers I provided as a response to the browser:

[image: provided headers]

I believe this could be a defect in the gzencode function of the production server or something. what am I doing wrong? Can anyone give any help with the information I provided?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you get those same response headers in both cases?

Comment: I disable zlib.output_compression with ini_set and all works